# Web-scrape project writing too much information

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to modify the code below to scrape jobs from www.itoworld.com/careers. The jobs are in a table format and return all the <'td> values.

I believe it comes from the line:

```
var parentnode = node.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.FirstChild.NextSibling
```

However, I want it to write:

```
<a  class="std-btn" href="http://www.itoworld.com/office-manager/">Office Manager</a>
```

Currently it is writing

```
<a href='http://www.itoworld.com/office-manager/' target='_blank'>Office ManagerOffice & AdminCambridgeFind out more</a>
```

I plan on 'brute force' modifying the output to remove unnecessary extras but was hoping there is a smarter way to do this. Is there a way for example to remove the second and third ParentNode after they have been called? (So they do not get written?)

```
public string ExtractIto()
    {
        string sUrl = "http://www.itoworld.com/careers/";
        GlobusHttpHelper ghh = new GlobusHttpHelper();
        List<Links> link = new List<Links>();

        bool Next = true;
        int count = 1;

        string html = ghh.getHtmlfromUrl(new Uri(string.Format(sUrl)));
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hd = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        hd.LoadHtml(html);
        var hn = hd.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='btn-wrapper']");

        var hnc = hn.SelectNodes(".//a");

        foreach (var node in hnc)
        {

            try
            {
                var parentnode = node.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.FirstChild.NextSibling; 
                Links l = new Links();
                l.Name = ParseHtmlContainingText(parentnode.InnerText);     
                l.Link = node.GetAttributeValue("href", "");


                link.Add(l);


            }

        }


        string Xml = getXml(link);

        return WriteXml(Xml);
```

For completeness below is the definition of ParseHtmlContainingText

```
 public string ParseHtmlContainingText(string htmlString)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlString), @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", ""), @"\s{2,}", " ").Trim(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a "name node" and use that for your parse method.

I tested with this code and it worked for me.

```
            var parentnode = node.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.FirstChild.NextSibling;
            var nameNode = parentnode.FirstChild;

            Links l = new Links();
            l.Name = ParseHtmlContainingText(nameNode.InnerText);
            l.Link = node.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
```

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you very much. I shall try and understand the inheritance better.